# Swift Mailer Swift_Attachment class not found

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I am attaching PDF into email, PDF is generated through mPDF and it's generated perfectly. But when I try to attach it into email using Swift Mailer it's always giving me class error that `Swift_Attachment class not found`

Code

```
require __DIR__.'/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift.php';

$attachment = new Swift_Attachment($html, 'phpflow.pdf', 'application/pdf');

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
  ->setSubject('Here is the subject')
  ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))
  ->setTo(array('acb@gmail.com'))
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
  ->attach($attachment);

$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$mailer->send($message);
$mpdf->Output($filename ,'I');
```

I don't know what's wrong here, suggest me

Comment: Why not use print debugging to see if your dependency is actually imported properly?

Comment: @chb How to do it?